# Defining and adding image width using jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags, width, image

I am developing an eCommerce shop where on over 100 category pages, the thumbnails are not the same size and/or proportion. I need to center all images with the class Thumbnail within its div. I have already added a relative position to the item as well as a margin to center.

Can someone help me write a quick jquery that will add get the width of each image with the class thumbnail and add it to each img tag?

```
.thumbnail {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Perhaps something like this is a start. I need to search the document for each image with a certain class, then get the width of each image and add it as css.

```
$(document).find(".Thumbnail").css({
width: $(this).width()
});
```

Comment: How about you try to write it yourself and open a new question if and when you run into a problem implementing it?

Comment: You need to post some markup so we can see how this looks and where to move what etc. And a better explanation of what exactly it is you're trying to do would'nt hurt either.

Comment: I was basically just asking how you would search for each image, define it's width and add it to the tag. I didn't know how to write that, and I didnt find anything searching.

Comment: How does your HTML looks like?

Comment: Thanks for all the love guys! Thought this was about helping people.

Comment: as free advice; make your server process the images upon upload so they end up with the same width & the same aspect ratio; php does that very well & no layout surprise after

Comment: you're not helping yourself either counting on other to do your job from a to z

Comment: Thanks for the server advice. I should have made my question simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess, but as I understand, your Markup looks a like this:

```
...

<div class='product'>
  <img src='image.jpg' class='thumbnail' />
</div>

<div class='product'>
  <img src='image2.jpg' class='thumbnail' />
</div>

...
```

if you now want to equalize the thumbnail-width to the parent simply use CSS:

```
.product {
 margin: 0px;
 width: 200px; // just as an example
 height: 200px; // just as an example
 float: left; // just as an example
 margin: 0px 7px 7px 0px; // just as an example
}

.thumbnail {
 width: 100%;
}
```

the use of jQuery for this need is a waste of performance but you could do it like this:

```
$(".thumbnail").each(function() {
 $(this).css({
      "width" : $(this).parent().width()+"px"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set the parent div position to

```
position: relative;
```

and then set the item

```
margin : 0 auto;
```